# On-topic question migrated to Physics?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently, [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/154337/revisions) about the charge polarity convention was migrated to Physics.

On Physics, it will likely be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/why-is-the-charge-naming-convention-wrong?rq=1) or maybe another one.

But wouldn't it be on topic to also have a canonical question on EE explaining that the charge polarity convention is arbitrary?

Comment: But that deviates from ***"Operation: Migrate EVERYTHING"***

Comment: @W5VO That's a pretty bad attitude to have as a mod.

Comment: Different SEs seem to have different opionions on this, but the majority seems to see themselves as "information islands" where everything ontopic stays and is answered, no matter if it has an answer anywhere else.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, we've discussed the general question on meta before, and I think we've concluded that yes, it's okay to answer questions that could also be answered on other stacks. Because the answer you get might depend on which stack you ask. So really, I'm asking about this question specifically. Why was it considered off topic?

Comment: Anyway, I got +4 for [this answer](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/plethora-of-overlapping-se-sites-and-concerns-about-them/3993#3993).

Comment: @ThePhoton: I have no idea, if it was me, I would have never considered to migrate it, but its topicness is borderline to electronics design, so if it had been rephrased better it might have stayed here.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine if the question is migrated and then closed as a duplicate.  The questioner gets pointed to the correct answer, which I think should be the goal.  Having a question closed as a duplicate is not a punishment, it's how SE is supposed to work to get people looking for answers pointed to answers while keeping signal to noise high.

Comment: But it should also be fine if we answer it on EE, right?

Comment: Actually migrations are a little different to being closed as a duplicate. They end up deleted here and count towards question throttling and bans: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248666/203972. While the user has two other questions migrated that were certainly off-topic here when all three are deleted in 30 days I suspect it'll push them over the limit more.

Comment: I suppose it would count as a migration here, and closed as a duplicate at physics.

Comment: By having more than one question migrated in a span of 30 days, that user can rationally be expected to have already been made aware of what counts as off topic.